# Measure the height of DrawHTMLText before drawing on document with Debenu Quick PDF Lib

Tags: c#, pdf

I am using latest version of Debenu Quick PDF Library.

Is it possible to calculate the height of [DrawHTMLText](http://www.debenu.com/docs/pdf_library_reference/DrawHTMLText.php) before drawing it on document?

I need it because, I want my application to decide where (x,y coordinates) to draw `DrawHTMLText` according to its dimensions.

For example if it exceeds document border from the bottom side I want it to pull it up to make it fit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

user3253797,

You can use the GetHTMLTextHeight function to determine the height before calling DrawHTMLText.

http://www.debenu.com/docs/pdf_library_reference/GetHTMLTextHeight.php

Note : DrawHTMLText will return any overflow text as a string that will not fit into the specified area.  GetHTMLTextHeight should in theory return the text height for the text that can fit inside the box.  If the text is too long to fit inside the one box then it sounds like you will need to modify the x,y positions and possibly the HTML text itself to make it all fit on one page.

Good luck.

Andrew.